# How to load an unknown list of property files in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

If I have a unknown size list of files to load, `resourceList`, how can y load it?

I have seen the use of `@PropertySources`, but it seems I can't use this method, because I only know the file list after execution, (I get it through an operation with a VM argument, and the files are external).

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:anotherbunchof.properties")
})
```

I have tried PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        List<String>configLocations = loadConfigLocations();
        List<Resource> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();
        configLocations.forEach(location -> resourceList.add(new FileSystemResource(location)));
        configurer.setLocations(resourceList.toArray(new Resource[]{}));
        return configurer;
    }
```

But **this only resolves annotations** `@Value("${...`.
If I try to get some property **through the Environment, it is null**.

```
@Autowire
Environment env;
...
String myProp = env.getProperty("my.property")
```

Comment: Depending on the exact situation, [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles) might be a viable solution. To provide a more concrete answer I'd need to have more details about exactly how you want to use the properties you want to load based on configuration.

Comment: @E-Riz Basically, I load a list of properties file paths after execution (`List<String>configLocations = loadConfigLocations()`) . I need to load all those properties so they could be available through annotations `@Value("${....` and through the `Environment.getProperty(name)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ApplicationStartedEvent or ApplicationReadyEvent and update your properties as per your requirement.

Optionally, you can use `CommandLineRunner` interface also.

They will be running in the following order

```
ApplicationStartedEvent 
CommandLinerRunner
ApplicationReadyEvent
```

Comment: I have read that the properties update is delicate, because some beans like DataSources may need them, and so on. So I am trying find a way of properly initialize them at the beginning of the app start, but I don't know how.

I am trying now with a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer.initialize()`, but it is not working either.

Comment: Please provide more details so I can analyze more. A git repo url would be helpful.